# Помогите разобраться с Subscriptions

Tags: android, google-play-console

Читая документацию по in-App/Subscriptions, не понял один момент - для того, что бы добавить подписки в приложение, нужно загрузить apk в консоль с разрешением BILLING, потом создать подписки, после этого писать логику в коде и опять перезагружать apk? Или можно изначально описать логику подписок в коде, загрузить apk и после создать подписки?

Comment: 2 вариант......

Comment: Понял, спасибо!